# Exporting shapefiles with symbology using ArcGIS Pro for use in ArcGIS Runtime

Tags: shapefile, symbology, export, arcgis-pro, arcgis-runtime

I have a set of shapefiles with elevation values in its attribute. In ArcGIS Pro, I have placed these shapefiles into a `Scene` as a 3D layer. Then I have added extrusion, and the shapefiles are rendered correctly with height.

I tried to load the shapefiles into a `Scene` in ArcGIS Runtime, and did the extrusion in code. However, the symbology (or the color) is lost. I am aware that I can hard-code each shapefile's symbology in code, but that sounds wrong to me.

Is there a way for me to export these from ArcGIS Pro and use them in ArcGIS Runtime without hard-coding anything?

#### Update

This is what I am currently doing in code:

```
private async void LoadShapefiles(Scene sc) {
    foreach (var file in GetPaths()) {
        ShapefileFeatureTable myShapefile = await ShapefileFeatureTable.OpenAsync(file);

        FeatureLayer layer = new FeatureLayer(myShapefile);
        var symbol = new SimpleFillSymbol(SimpleFillSymbolStyle.Solid, Colors.Gray, null); // Hard-coded
        var renderer = new SimpleRenderer(symbol);


        renderer.SceneProperties.ExtrusionMode = Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Symbology.ExtrusionMode.Maximum;
        renderer.SceneProperties.ExtrusionExpression = "[HEIGHT]";

        layer.Renderer = renderer;
        layer.RenderingMode = FeatureRenderingMode.Dynamic;

        sc.OperationalLayers.Add(layer);
    }
}

private string[] GetPaths() {
    return Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\Test", "*.shp");
}
```

This causes all features to be rendered with the same color.

Comment: You could try loading them as a layer instead of as a feature class.. do you have any code so we can see where to implement potential fixes?

Comment: @MichaelStimson Updated.